# Windows phone 8.1 filter collectionviewsource

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, filter, windows-phone-8.1, collectionviewsource

In Windows phone 8 I used to filter my `collectionviewsource` using `Filter` predicate. Now in 8.1 it disappeared.

How can I filter my `collectionviewsource` now? Or my `listview`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See this example [A WinRT CollectionView class with Filtering and Sorting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So)